# python regex for operating system name

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to get regex for operating system name: Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, windows 8.1 and windows server 2008 R2

Normally the operating system name is in a line, for example:
Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144)
I tried this regex `:\s*(\w+\s*\w*\.\w|\s])`

which is only good till Windows 8.1, what would be a good regex for all the above mentioned operating system name. Have been trying for hours thank you for help.

Comment: windows series are you only target or not?

Comment: Will it always be preceded by "Operating System: " and followed by "64-bit" or "32-bit"? If so... you could do something like `(?<=Operating System:\s*)(.*?)(?=\s*\d+\-bit)`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr ya only windows series like: Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, windows 8.1 and windows server 2008 R2
the name of operating systems is only what I want to parse thank you

Comment: @smerny it will always be preceded by "Operating System:" I am not sure about bits

Comment: If you're looking for something specific like that and want to be the safest (not capturing extras)... there aren't that many options so you could do something like this even.. `(Windows (?:XP|Vista|7|8|8\.1|Server 2008 R2))`

Comment: @smerny it prints the whole line as it i tried this `"Windows(:XP|Vista|7|8|8\.1|Server 2008 R2)"`

Comment: it's better to build your only dataset. in my opinion, /^windows\s+.+/i should be enough. who knows what windows will be in the future?

Comment: @Tokin, I'm not sure what you mean but what you posted is not what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex. Use this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'posix'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
>>> platform.release()
'2.6.22-15-generic'
```

This works for all operating systems.

Comment: I was trying to parse it in from a line, was not trying to get the os-name from the system. Thank you!